# X setInputFocus - dwm and SFML

Tags: c++, linux, sfml, x11, x-dwm

I'm using Arch Linux with dwm window manager (yup, I know it's not longer supported). Currently I'm developing small application in C++ using SFML graphics library. Whenever I try to run any application with this library I get this error:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  42 (X_SetInputFocus)
  Serial number of failed request:  80
  Current serial number in output stream:  89
```

Xorg logs print nothing, I also tried installing xlibs (but it was already installed), different version of SFML, dwm, getting drunk, everything. Funny thing is that on my friend's notebook with the same version of SFMl and dwm (but on Ubuntu) - everything works fine.
If it's not possible to get any answer connected exactly with this problem, 
I'd like to know if it's possible to get any logs connected with X input.
Thanks.

Comment: Here's a possible [issue report](https://github.com/SFML/SFML/issues/991). If you hit a roadblock, it might be worth trying the workarounds in the bug report or a build a SFML with the proposed patch applied.

Comment: I feel like drinking should have fixed it. Are you sure you are getting drunk correctly?